# Restrict google maps/use strictBounds to autocomplete by region

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, limit, restrict

I am using Google Maps Autocomplete and trying to restrict my results only to the Balkan region. As Google Maps currently have an option to restrict autocomplete to just 5 countries, this is not an option for me - trying to find a workaround.
I found a solution for the EU, but cannot work out how to set it for the Balkan region.

```
function initialize() {
  var options = {
    region:'EU',
    types: ['(cities)']
   };
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), options);
}
```

Wondering if strictBounds can be an option?

Comment: Hi Elektra, could you please add the code as text and format it as code? Images don't really help.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie :)

Comment: `strictBounds`: A boolean value, indicating that the Autocomplete widget should only return those places that are inside the bounds of the Autocomplete widget at the time the query is sent. Setting strictBounds to false (which is the default) will make the results biased towards, but not restricted to, places contained within the bounds. **But** a `LatLngBounds` object is a rectangle. So you might not be able to restrict to ONLY the EXACT region you are after.

Comment: I have been able to achieve something close to what I'm after using the follow: `defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(34.658666, 15.418504),
            new google.maps.LatLng(46.734827, 29.116564)
        );

        options = {
            bounds: defaultBounds,
            types: ['(cities)'],
            strictBounds: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming to this question over a year later. You would need to use the bounds option for limiting to an area.

Here is my code for restricting to a rectangle area over Europe.

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(35.929631, -25.022766),
    new google.maps.LatLng(71.344983, 49.860046)
);

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById("element-id"),
    {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        strictBounds: true,
        types: ['(regions)']
    }
);
```

You can use this tool to get your own rectangle area
http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html